# Log Mediator settings in WSO2 Proxy Service

Tags: proxy, wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

I'm creating a proxy-service with a log-mediator in WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 6.1.1 and I have 2 simple questions:

1)Is it possible to costumize the format of the logged request/response? Actually what I see in the WSO2 consolle is the XML rapresentation of my request/response, and I would like to change them in other format (for example JSON).

2)Is it possible to costumize the file name/location where WSO2 logs the request/response?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The log mediator will log the payload as it is at the time of reaching the mediator. The reason you see it as XML (even if it was a JSON) is because the message was built by ESB and during building it is converted to XML. If you need to see the payload as JSON, convert the payload to JSON with the following property and log again.

```
<property name="messageType" action="set" scope="axis2" value="application/json" type="STRING"/>
```

For the second question, you can configure where to store log files in the `$CARBON_HOME/repository/conf/log4j.properties` file.

```
log4j.appender.CARBON_LOGFILE.File=${carbon.home}/repository/logs/${instance.log}/wso2carbon${instance.log}.log
```

Refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Configuring+Log4j+Properties for more details on configuring logger.

Comment: In which way the property tag has to be specified? In this way?

         <log level="custom">
            <property name="messageType" value="application/json"/>
         </log>

Comment: It should be a property mediator to be added as I have mentioned in the answer. Not within log mediator. Refer : https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Property+Mediator

Comment: It doesn't work. Below there is a snippet of  the source of my proxy with the property mediator... Is it correct?: 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="hl7testproxy"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="hl7,http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
        <property name="messageType" action="set" scope="axis2" 
        value="application/json" type="STRING"/>
      </inSequence>
.......
</proxy>

Answer (score 0):

As Maheeka told you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<proxy xmlns="ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="hl7testproxy" startOnLoad="true" statistics="disable" trace="disable" transports="hl7,http,https"> 
<target> 
<inSequence> 
<property name="messageType" action="set" scope="axis2" value="application/json" type="STRING"/> 
<log level="full"/> 
</inSequence> 
</proxy>
```

Also if yu want logs per proxy service see this page:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Per-Service+Logs+in+WSO2+ESB